# what does "that did it" mean here?

Tags: phrase-meaning

He put a fat white hand on Drioli's arm and began to push him firmly to the door.

> That did it.

"Take your goddam hands off me!"

Comment: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/that-does-it

Answer (score 4):

It's the past tense of

> That does it!

Which Kreiri in a comment supplied a link to [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/that-does-it):

> said when someone or something goes further than the limit of what is acceptable

This is what it means in your context.

However, in other contexts, it can have quite a different meaning  namely, *that action accomplished (did) it*.

> Try fishing over there. You might have better luck!
>   Yup, that did it!

*That* refers to whatever action (fishing over there)  led to the accomplishment or doing of the goal (having better luck catching fish).

One can also say:

> That did the trick!

and it means the same.